# failing to fetch method requireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I am experiencing some strange issue. I have this

```
require({
    paths: {
        'template': 'tmpl.min',
        'videoupload.widget': 'jquery.ui.videoupload'
    }
}, ['js/main_video.js'], function(App) {
    App.initial_video_upload();
});
```

and this

```
define(['template','videoupload.widget'],function() {
        function initial_video_upload(){
            'use strict';
            $('#videoupload').videoupload({
                //...some code
            });
        }
        return{
            initial_video_upload: initial_video_upload
        }
    }
);
```

in the file `jquery.ui.videoupload.js`, I have some call to a `tmpl` method which is defined in `tmpl.min.js`, but I get the message

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tmpl'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here:

1. Your first snippet is passing configuration options to a `require` function. `require`, is a way to load dependencies and execute some code using them. If you want to pass configuration options to require.js,  [`requirejs.config`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config) is what you want:

   ```
   // configurations to be used in your module definitions
   requirejs.config({
       paths: {
           'template': 'tmpl.min',
           'videoupload.widget': 'jquery.ui.videoupload'
       }
   });

   // load your main module and kick things off
   require(['js/main_video.js'], function(App) {
       App.initial_video_upload();
   });)
   ```
2. Your second snippet is declaring dependencies, but not passing them into the callback:

   ```
   define(['template','videoupload.widget'], 
   // these are now accessible within the function's scope:
   function(template, videoupload.widget) {
           function initial_video_upload(){
               'use strict';
               $('#videoupload').videoupload({
                   //...some code
               });
           }
           return{
               initial_video_upload: initial_video_upload
           }
       }
   );
   ```

Additionally, I'm assuming jQuery is a dependency of your videoupload.widget. How are you loading that? You may need to add an additional "shim" configuration to your requirejs.config:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'template': 'tmpl.min',
        'videoupload.widget': 'jquery.ui.videoupload'
    },
    shim: {
      "videoupload.widdget": ["jquery"]
    }
});
```

Comment: Still getting the same error after updating to `function(template, videoupload.widget)`... Btw, `jQuery` is loaded by `require(['js/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js'])` at the top of the file

Comment: I think there may be something wrong with the structure of your file, could you post it (or more excerpts, if it is too largE). Typically, you should be using one require per file.

Comment: Hi again : I am still experiencing troubles. In fact, Iget two successive messages : `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tmpl'`and then `Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: tmpl`. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: I tried to set the `requirejs.config` `waitSeconds` to 200, then to 0, but now I am getting no error message but the script `main_video` doesn't launch